# Is modifying the internal bytes of a const object undefined behavior in case it contains another object constructed by placement new?

Tags: c++, standards, undefined-behavior, placement-new

Consider the following example:

```
#include <new>

struct FunctionObject
{
    int operator()() // non-const, modifies the state of this object
    {
        i += 1;
        j += 2;
        return i + j;
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
};

struct Wrapper
{
    explicit Wrapper(const FunctionObject& input_object)
    {
        constructed_object = ::new (buffer) FunctionObject(input_object);
    }

    ~Wrapper()
    {
        constructed_object->~FunctionObject();
    }

    int operator()() const // const, but invokes the non-const operator() of the internal FunctionObject
    {
        return (*constructed_object)(); // this call modifies the internal bytes of this Wrapper
    }

    alignas(FunctionObject) unsigned char buffer[sizeof(FunctionObject)];
    FunctionObject* constructed_object = nullptr;
};

int test()
{
    const FunctionObject function_object{3, 4};
    const Wrapper object_wrapper{function_object}; // this call modifies the internal bytes of a const Wrapper
    return object_wrapper();
}
```

A `Wrapper` contains an internal `FunctionObject` which is constructed inside the `Wrapper` by a placement new.

The `Wrapper` object is `const`, its `operator()` is also `const`, but calling it causes the internal state of the object to be modified. In many cases, similar scenarios are undefined behavior in C++.

The question is, is it undefined behavior in this particular case (~ do I need to mark the `buffer` as `mutable`?), or does the C++ standard allow writing code like this?

Comment: I don't see why it should not be UB.

Comment: This is essentially the same as a const object that saves a non-const pointer to itself during construction, right?

Comment: @user253751 Kind of. With the difference that this const object constructs another (non-const) object within itself, and modifies that other object after construction. I.e., `Wrapper` modifies `FunctionObject`, but not itself directly, though that `FunctionObject` happens to be located inside the `Wrapper`'s internal bytes. Thus the ambiguity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Undefined Behavior.

From [dcl.type.cv],

> Any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime results in
> undefined behavior.

Adding the `mutable` specifier to `buffer` will allow it to be modified by a `const` member function.

Answer (score 1):

From [[class.mfct.non-static.general/4]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mfct.non-static):

> A non-static member function may be declared `const` [...]. These cv-qualifiers affect the type of the `this` pointer. They also affect the function type of the member function; a member function declared `const` is a *const* member function [...].

Then from  [[class.this/1]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mfct.non-static#class.this):

> The type of `this` in a member function whose type has a *cv-qualifier-seq cv* and whose class is `x` is "pointer to cv x". [*Note 1*: Thus in a const member function, the object for which the function is called is accessed through a **const access path**. -- *end note*]

And eventually from [[dcl.type.cv/3-4]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.type.cv):

> [...] a const-qualified access path **cannot be used to modify an object** [...]

> Any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime results in **undefined behavior**.

Hence, your `test()` routine shows undefined behavior, and that even if your Wrapper object `object_wrapper`wasn't `const`.

Answer (score 0):

No. It won't be undefined behaviour from practice, forget about what "standard" describes. It will behave just like without the "const".

The reason is that the "const" qualifier for an object in C++ is merely to tell the compiler to generate a compilation error in the case where some members or functions inside the object get invoked. Besides that, adding a "const" qualifier to an object doesn't results in different binaries after compilation.

This is different from the "const" qualifier applied on primitive types, such as "const int", "const char *". A variable of type "const int" will probably replaced by its compile-time value for optimization purpose. A string literal of type "const char *" will refer to some memory page that has read access limitation by the OS in such a way that modifying the memory content will let to crash of the program.

Also, a "const" qualifier of a function does result in different function signatures and can be treated like a function overloading.

Comment: thanks, but I can't agree with this: 'forget about what "standard" describes' -- I'd prefer not to, if the cost is nothing but adding one extra word (`mutable`) to just one line of code, and this way everyone will be happy